problem in connecting gstreamer's decodebin to autoaudiosink
I wonder why decodebin can directly connect to autovideosink, but it can NOT directly connect to autoaudiosink!
$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=myfile.mp4 ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink [not OK]
$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=myfile.mp4 ! decodebin ! autovideosink [OK]

I tested your pipeline and it worked on my side, which error are you seeing? Maybe you can add more debug to the command, for example:
GST_DEBUG=2 gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=myfile.mp4 ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink -v

Could you try this one?
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=myfile.mp4 ! qtdemux ! avdec_aac ! autoaudiosink

You could also try adding an audioconvert before the sink

Your second solution doesn't work either.
The error is:
Additional debug info:
gst/parse/grammar.y(540): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
failed delayed linking some pad of GstDecodeBin named decodebin0 to some pad of GstAutoAudioSink named autoaudiosink0
Redistribute latency...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gst/isomp4/qtdemux.c(6749): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0:

I got it working on my side using a .mp4 file I downloaded, maybe your file is not stable. Could you try testing using another MP4 file?
You can also try creating a file with this video pipe:
gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc ! x264enc ! mp4mux name=mp4 ! filesink location=/tmp/test1.mp4 audiotestsrc ! avenc_aac ! mp4.

still the same error with your file "test1.mp4" . . .

Try including an audioconvert: gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/tmp/test1.mp4 ! qtdemux ! avdec_aac ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink

It works! Isn't it (audioconvert) supposed to be inside decodebin?
